# jquery carousel with hover effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, carousel

Here's the URL: http://174.120.239.48/~peakperf/

Here's the jQuery:

http://pastebin.com/fB16ahcZ

Site is still under heavy development.

If you mouse over "Services retention" on the carousel you will see what the function should work like. on hover a span element is faded in, on mouse out it hides. Some are stuck, some work fine. Also notice that when you click the right arrow and scroll through the carousel the spans get stuck "on".

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your mark up is invalid as it is missing a closing "a" tag (see below)

```
</a>
```

Here is the error in your code.

```
           <a href="#" id="homeslide6-show">
               <img src="http://174.120.239.48/~peakperf/wp-content/themes/strausberg/images/home_service_retention.jpg" width="200" height="92" />
          </li>
      </ul>
```

Additionally your jquery code could be reduced by about 90% by using the each() function.

For example add a id to your ul and do it like so

```
<ul id="mycarousel">
```

---

```
    jQuery('#mycarousel').find('span').each(function(){

        jQuery(this).hover(function() {

            jQuery(this).next().fadeIn('slow');

            return false;

        }, function(){

            jQuery(this).next().fadeOut('slow');

            return false;
        });
    });
```

---

Ps, this code is fixed to the current html structure, you should use classes for making it more flexible

Comment: I tried your code but my spans didn't show on hover even with an id for my carousel. Thanks for the help, it's greatly appreciated. I'll keep working on it and see what i can come up with.

Comment: did you fix your html, andd the id to the carousel and use the other parts of your jquery combined with mine?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have several tags with the same ID, which is not allowed. The ID is `"homeslide6-show"`. You should also try stopping the animation, before starting and simplify your JavaScript to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
    jQuery('#homeslide1, #homeslide2, #homeslide3, #homeslide4, #homeslide5, #homeslide6').hide();

    // shows the slickbox on clicking the noted link Â 
    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        jQuery('#homeslide' + i + '-show').parent().hover(
            function(e, i) {
                jQuery('#homeslide' + i).stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            },
            function(e, i){
                jQuery('#homeslide' + i).stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        );
    }
});
```

and let me know if this works.

EDITED

My javascript above is incorrect. The following works:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
    jQuery('#homeslide1, #homeslide2, #homeslide3, #homeslide4, #homeslide5, #homeslide6').hide();

    // shows the slickbox on clicking the noted link Â 
    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        jQuery('#homeslide' + i + '-show').parent().data({element: '#homeslide' + i}).hover(
            function() {
                var element = jQuery('element');
                jQuery(element).stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
                return false;
            },
            function(){
                var element = jQuery('element');
                jQuery(element).stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
                return false;
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you find multiple id's with #homeslide6-show neil? I couldnt find that duplicated myself.

Comment: Thanks for the effort Neil! Tried your code. Uploaded it and it's not showing the spans on hover. Bummer.  The multiple id's are because the carousel created them dynamically. Nothing I can really do about that.

Comment: @Blowsie, it's really strange, Firebug shows two <a> tags with that same ID, but looking at the source under IE8, there is only one tag. I think that the fact you do not have a closing </a> tag for it is confusing firebug.

Comment: I closed that <a> tag. Don't know why firebug is "bugging" out.

Comment: I changed the id's to classes and it works perfectly now. Thank you all for your time and effort!

Comment: @wilwaldon: Please consider accepting this answer (click the green check mark next to the answer score) if it's the one that helped you the most.  Thank you.